# Prompt for User Input and turn it into an environment variable

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to make a script that gives me my current public IP, and asks the user for a new IP that should be declared as an environment variable for ubuntu, however even tho the MASTER variable is working as intended the SLAVE one isn't. here's a minimum sample of my script

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo $SHELLOPTS 
set -o allexport                #All variables are auto set to export
MASTER=`ip addr | grep inet | grep 10. | tail -1 | sed 's/^ *//g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sed 's/\/.*$//g'`
echo Master IP is: $MASTER
echo Insert the new IP:
read input
SLAVE=$input
echo Master IP is: $MASTER
echo Slave IP is: $SLAVE
```

Even tho the variable is actually printed, it cannot be reused more than once as an environment variable, I have been looking around this problem with no luck, any help will be really appreciated

[image]

Comment: If you want the shell variables to continue to exist after the script has finished, you need to *source* the script, like `. scriptname`.  If you *execute* it rather than *source* it, it is run in a subshell and all environmental changes are lost when the subshell exits.

Comment: Or dont use a script at all but a function defined in .bashrc

Comment: @John1024 This actually made it work, im sourcing the script, and works as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit ~/.bashrc and add to the bottom:

```
leonid@DevSSD:~$ tail -n 7  ~/.bashrc
getIP() {
  export MASTER=`ip addr | grep inet | grep 10. | tail -1 | sed 's/^ *//g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sed 's/\/.*$//g'`
  echo "Master IP is: $MASTER"
  echo "Insert the new IP:"
  read input
  export SLAVE="$input"
}
```

Type in shell prompt: `$ getIP`

```
leonid@DevSSD:~$ getIP
Master IP is: 192.168.1.101
Insert the new IP:
10.0.0.1
```

Then you may check if var is set:

```
leonid@DevSSD:~$ env|grep MASTER
MASTER=192.168.1.101
leonid@DevSSD:~$ env|grep SLAVE
SLAVE=10.0.0.1
```